# logoutSuccessUrl not working in Spring Boot

Tags: security, spring-boot

I have a simple Gradle Spring Boot (v 1.3.3) WebMVC application I'm running from the command line via "Gradle bootrun". I am also including Spring Security and am overriding some default security configuration by including a java security config class. My build file is

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'readinglist'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

My security configuration class is

```
package readinglist;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/readingList").access("hasRole('READER')")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
      .and()
        .logout()
           .logoutSuccessUrl("/");  // Added .and()....logoutSuccessURL()
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(
              AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
          UserDetails userDetails = readerRepository.findOne(username);
          if (userDetails != null) {
            return userDetails;
          }
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found.");
        }
      });
  }

}
```

I also have a home controller that maps the URL "/" to the view home.html
When I run the application and go to localhost:8080/ I get the home page.
When I try to access the URL "/readingList", I get the custom login page. If I enter incorrect credentials, I return to the login page for another try. If I enter valid credentials I get the readingList page. So far so good. The problem is with the logoutSuccessURL("/"). When I go to the URL "/logout" this should log me out and take me back to "/", but instead I get the following error showing in the browser:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Mar 03 19:31:24 PST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I turned on debug for security and when I hit my logout link I get the following:

```
2016-03-03 19:48:45.033 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2016-03-03 19:48:45.033 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2016-03-03 19:48:45.036 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2016-03-03 19:48:45.036 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2016-03-03 19:48:45.046 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2016-03-03 19:48:45.047 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@7ae1a0fb] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2016-03-03 19:48:45.047 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@7ae1a0fb] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-03-03 19:48:45.055 DEBUG 22401 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

I'm not sure why DispatcherServlet is trying to lookup "/error". I am also not being logged out since if I try to go to the URL "/readingList" again, I am not prompted for credentials.

I did a little more testing by loggin in, then going to the URL "/logout" manually. I got the following in my log:

```
2016-03-04 16:39:31.170 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /logout reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-03-04 16:39:31.170 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/logout]
2016-03-04 16:39:31.170 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /logout
2016-03-04 16:39:31.171 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/logout]
2016-03-04 16:39:31.171 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/logout] are [/**]
2016-03-04 16:39:31.171 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/logout] are {}
2016-03-04 16:39:31.172 DEBU                G 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/logout] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@e146f93]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-03-04 16:39:31.172 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/logout] is: -1
2016-03-04 16:39:31.172 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-03-04 16:39:31.173 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-03-04 16:39:31.173 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-03-04 16:39:31.173 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-03-04 16:39:31.196 DEBUG 24395 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
....
```

It seems like the "/logout" URL is not working which I don't undertand. I though the default logout URL is "/logout".

Comment: `/logout` works by default only with a POST.. So only going to `/logout` isn't going to work as that is GET not a POST. To have it work with a GET you would need to disable CSFR protection (which is enabled by default).

Comment: That must be a change in Spring Security at some point. As I said, I have some other Spring Security projects where I set /logout and did not have to disable CSRF or set it to POST or POST/GET with logoutRequestMatcher(...).

Comment: In Spring Security 4 the filters are enabled by default in earlier versions they are only enabled when using java config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution in a similar project here, http://spr.com/part-5-integrating-spring-security-with-spring-boot-web/. In my security config I changed

```
.logout()
  .logoutSuccessUrl("/")  
  .and()
    ...
```

to

```
.logout()
   .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/")  
      .and()
      ...
```

I'm not sure if this is the "preferred" solution, and I don't know why the call to logoutRequestMatcher(...) is needed. I have other (non-Spring-Boot) Spring Security projects that don't use the call to logoutRequestMatcher(...), and the .logout(...).logoutSuccessUrl(...) call works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
            .and()      
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll();
```

i prefer this solution because it wipe the session data so you can't access anymore try it yousrself to make sure open the developer tools in the browser and see the session !!